# Page is getting refreshed after closing new window which was opened from the main page

Tags: asp.net

I have a page where in I have a grid control with Image button as one othe ItemFiled.
When I click on the image in any binded row, I am opening one new window which is again a aspx page. 
The problem is when I close the new window, the page from where the button is clicked is getting refresh, which is not required for me. It should be in it's state and should not be refreshed.

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: share your markup and code behind

Answer (score 0):

In ImageButton: `OnClientClick="return showPopup();"`

Add at the end of showPopup function: `return false;`